# This "Single - pass wire frame shader "opengl shader worked on my old machine with amd integrated graphics but it dose not my new nvidea pc

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader

I created this shader from following this tutorial on single pass wireframe rendering: http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/

Fragment:

```
#version 450
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
in vec3 vBC;
const float lineWidth = 0.5;
const vec3 color = vec3(0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
float edgeFactor(){
    vec3 d = fwidth(vBC);
    vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d*1.5, vBC);
    return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);
}
void main(){
    outColor = vec4(min(vec3(edgeFactor()), color), 1.0);
}
```

Vertex:

```
#version 450
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 baryCentric;
out vec3 vBC;
uniform mat4 T_MVP;
void main() {
  //texCoord0 = texCoord;    
  gl_Position = T_MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
  vBC = baryCentric;
}
```

And here is the gl prep before rendering:

```
wir.bind();
wir.updateUniforms(super.getTransform(), mat, engine);
GL45.glEnable(GL45.GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE);
GL45.glEnable(GL45.GL_BLEND);
GL45.glBlendFunc(GL45.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL45.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
mesh.draw("baryCentric", GL15.GL_TRIANGLES);
```

And here is how i bind the vertex atrribs;
[image: java]
[image: show]

The shader worked perfectly fine on my old amd integrated graphics card. But it dosnt on my rtx 2060 super.
Shader and Gl version
on old: OpenGL version: 4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.200.1062.1004
on new: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 445.87

Comment: Based on the image it looks as if your triangles are rendered in alternating clockwise/anti-clockwise winding order.  Is there anything elsewhere in the code that would affect front or back facing primitives specifically?  You might want to try `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` to see what (if any) effect that has.

Comment: Yeah it didnt have any effect other than render the faces inside the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I dont know what causes this but i think its the model files.

How i solved this was instead of pre processing the Bary centric coords i would calculate them or rather assign them in a geometry shader like so:

```
    vBC = vec3(1, 0, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    vBC = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    vBC = vec3(0, 0, 1);
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
```

and nothing else just pass them onto the fragment shader and it would do the rest:

```
#version 400
precision mediump float;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
in vec3 vBC;
const float lineWidth = 0.5;
const vec3 lineColor = vec3(0.7, 0.7, 0.7);

float edgeFactor() {
  vec3 d = fwidth(vBC);
  vec3 f = step(d * lineWidth, vBC);
  return min(min(f.x, f.y), f.z);
}

void main(){
    outColor = vec4(255, 191, 0.0, (1.0-edgeFactor())*0.95);        
}
```

The vertex shader only defines the positions nothing else the most basic.

Here is the full geometry shader if any one needs it:

```
#version 400
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
out vec3 vBC;
void main()
{

    vBC = vec3(1, 0, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    vBC = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    vBC = vec3(0, 0, 1);
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

 }
```

Here are some pictures:
[image: wireframe]
As you can see its working with transparency which is done using:
[image: code]

Here is the articles i looked at:
https://tchayen.github.io/wireframes-with-barycentric-coordinates/
http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/

And a cool book that helped me a lot:
https://people.inf.elte.hu/plisaai/pdf/David%20Wolff%20-%20OpenGL%204.0%20Shading%20Language%20Cookbook%20(2).pdf

Just in case here is the Vertex shader:

```
#version 400
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 T_MVP;

void main() {
  gl_Position = T_MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Where comes the geometry shader from? There is no geometry shader in the question. You have hidden this important information. This made it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: At first i did not have a gemetry shader in the original code, after a while researching i found out the way i was generating Bary coords was useless, so what i had learned from reading the shader cookbook i applied my knoledge and came up with the brilliant idea to assign bary coords at render. before i was genrating them by divideding the verticies by 3 and then looping over the remainder and adding 1,0,0 and 0,1,0 and 0,0,1 to a list and then suppling that list in an buffer to the shader in a different vao

Comment: And btw its not impossible to do this without a geometry shader if you actually spent time researching you would know.